# Initialization before we start a multithreading code

Tags: c++, x86, memory-barriers

```
int main(){
    // X is a shared resource
    initSharedResourceX();
    startMultitreadingServer(); // handle requests concurrently with function handle() <- below. All handlers (run concurrently) access to X **read-only**.


}

int handle(){
    return X.get(); // get() is read-only
}
```

I would like to avoid synchronization access to X by initialization a shared resource before we start. Do I need a compiler barrier? I can imagine that a compiler do someting like:

```
int main(){
    startMultitreadingServer(); 
}

int handle(){
    if(X is not initialized) {
        initSharedResourceX();
    }
    return X.get(); 
}
```

and as we can see it breaks our program.

I know, the compiler must be super-smart to do it. Especially, the compiler must know what does it mean to initialize X. So, it must really super-super-smart. 
But, can we assume that it is not?

What do you think?

Comment: you not need any memory barrier here (between what ?). and compiler of course can not move call  initSharedResourceX(); to handler

Comment: I would say thread creation is a memory barrier.

Comment: @RbMm, " and compiler of course can not move call initSharedResourceX(); to handler" because ...

Comment: @Jarod42, good point. Are you sure?

Comment: @Gilgamesz - because this absolute different code.

Comment: How do you measure difference of code, and how a compiler do it?

Comment: @Gilgamesz - are this is not obvious ? how call from one function can be moved to absolute another ? what is `X is not initialized` ? how compiler can at all generate this code. and your code not complete and exactly. if want complete and exactly answer - post such code. for your current pseudo code - i give answer

Comment: If you're creating a thread and making a system call to do it (which would be the case unless you have your application in a privileged context, like ring 0), it would create an implicit memory barrier as you perform a context switch.

Comment: `X is not initialized` - what is ? `initSharedResourceX` - what code ? `handle()` - from where and how called ? all this not visible. but from general view - 2 code spinets absolute different. compiler can do some optimization, which not change by sense program execution. however what you post - not optimization. this is absolute different by logic code

Comment: The compiler will not move the call to `initSharedResourceX` because to do so it needs to prove it is safe under the as-if rule. That would require knowing what `initShareResourceX` does, in order to generate the condition for the `if` (How can a compiler know that `X` is initialized?). `intSharedResourceX` doesn't need a full barrier but at least a "write release" as a last operation. Usually, however, thread creation is a synchronisation action. Check your thread creation library to see if that's the case.

Comment: @MargaretBloom, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a compiler **doesn't see the code** of `startMultitreadingServer` function, then it is prohibited (by a language specification) to move any code around an invocation of the function.

If a compiler **see the code** of `startMultitreadingServer` function, then it should found a **memory barrier** (or any operation which cause this effect) inside the function. (Any *thread-starting* function should have a memory barrier inside; this should be stated in its contract/description). And again, the compiler cannot move (at least, forward) any code around this barrier.

So, in any case a compiler cannot move the code, preceding the *thread-creation* function call, after that call.

Comment: ok, thanks. I didn't know that creation of thread is a barrier (but it seems to be reasonable). 
When we assume that there is no operation which cause a barrier, are my doubts sensible?

Comment: "When we assume that there is no operation which cause a barrier, are my doubts sensible?" - Without a barrier semantic thread creation function is likely *broken* - I can hardly imagine a function without internal barrier, which initializes memory for the new thread in CPU cache-safe manner. But if the function actually misses the barrier, then in some cases the compiler is allowed to move a code around the function's call.